# how show error message csv file does not exist

Tags: django, import-csv

> if i added a csv file name inccorrectly i wnat to show error message entered csv file does not exist please write the correct csv file name.how it make?

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
help = 'Load a company csv file into the database'

def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('filename.csv', type=str)

def handle(self, *args, **options ):
    if Company.objects.exists():
        print("Data already loaded!!")
    with open('companies.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            create= Company.objects.get_or_create(   
            name=row[0],
            hr_name=row[1],
            hr_email=row[2],
            hr_verified=row[3],
            user_id=row[4],
            primary_phone=row[5],
            comments=row[6],
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use a try except:

```
try:
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
       # ...
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print("Please write the correct cvs file name")
```

2. You can check if it exists the file:

```
import os


if not os.path.exists(filename):
    print("Please write the correct csv file name")
```

Comment: You can improve these examples with `raise CommandError` like the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Python question than a Django question. You can do it with a `try/catch` throwing `FileNotFoundError` exception when an incorrect file is given.

```
def handle(self, *args, **options ):
    if Company.objects.exists():
        print("Data already loaded!!")
    try:
        with open('companies.csv', 'r') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            ....
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # Yoour error message goes here
```